# Discord.py Blacklist a user from using my bot

Tags: discord.py

I want to blacklist certain users from using *All* commands of my bot. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome to the SO. Please take the [StackOverflow Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and look at the [how to ask good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [global check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#global-checks) that checks the id of the user against a list of banned ids:

```
@bot.check
async def blacklist(ctx):
    return ctx.author.id in get_user_blacklist()
```